# Scraping multiple iteration of same HTML from a webpage using google sheet script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In my use case, only google sheet script is the option (I do not have the option to use any server side language).

Currently, I am able to scrape data from a website by defining START and END html that bounds the data like this:

```
function getData() {
    var url = "https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/signaturesatori-central-s/fejomcfhljndadjlojamaklegghjnjfn?hl=en";
    var fromText = '<div class="e-f-ih"';
    var toText = '">';
  
    var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    var scraped = Parser
                    .data(content)
                    .from(fromText)
                    .to(toText)
                    .build();
    Logger.log(scraped);
    return scraped;
}
```

But, I just came across a webpage from where I need to scrape data but the data is in DIVs.
Yes, I can simply define the START and END of div with classname but the issue is that page inncludes a list and each item in the list is wrapped by a DIV with same class so above code only picks up 1st iteration.

Is there any way I can define or target iteration from where I need to extract data?

Like target 1st DIV and 3rd DIV?
Any way to define index number like

*FROM (which is START) = "<div class="myclass".[0];
TO (which is END) =*

or

*FROM (which is START) = "<div class="myclass".[2];
TO (which is END) =*

**Here is an example so show you what I am trying to accomplish:**

If this there is one DIV on a website with a unique class name like this:

```
<div class="list_item">
Item 1
<a href="https://www.site1.com">link1</a>
</div>
```

I am able to use the above posted code to extract the text in the DIV like this:

```
function getData() {
    var url = "https://here_goes_webpage_url.com";
    var fromText = '<div class="list_item">';
    var toText = '</div>';
  
    var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
    var scraped = Parser
                    .data(content)
                    .from(fromText)
                    .to(toText)
                    .build();
    Logger.log(scraped);
    return scraped;
}
```

**Output:**
Item 1
[link1](https://www.site1.com)

**Issue:**
Now, I am dealing with a webpage where there are multiple DIVs with exact same class name like this:

```
<div class="list_item">
Item 1
<a href="https://www.site1.com">link1</a>
</div>


<div class="list_item">
Item 2
<a href="https://www.site2.com">link2</a>
</div>

<div class="list_item">
Item 3
<a href="https://www.site3.com">link3</a>
</div>


<div class="list_item">
Item 4
<a href="https://www.site4.com">link4</a>
</div>


<div class="list_item">
Item 5
<a href="https://www.site5.com">link5</a>
</div>
```

Using the above code, only gives me first occurance of the item.

I would like to target and extract the following item **individually**:

*item 1
item 3
item 5*

How can I do that?

Comment: Can I ask you about the output values you expect?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike Thank you for commenting. I have updated my question and posted an example with the output, what I am trying to do and where I need help with the code. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for adding more information. In your URL, it seems that `<div class="list_item">` is not included in the HTML retrieved with UrlFetchApp. How about this?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike The page is not publically accessible, so I am unable to share the URL which is why I have used a TEST webpage URL my post so show my approach. I have shared the HTML which explains what I am trying to accomplish and where I need help with the code.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? At first, please confirm whether my understanding of your situation and goal is correct. If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- Your URL cannot be used.
- HTML data below `Issue: Now, I am dealing with a webpage where there are multiple DIVs with exact same class name like this:` can be retrieved from your URL. It is like below.

  ```
    <div class="list_item">
    Item 1
    <a href="https://www.site1.com">link1</a>
    </div>

    <div class="list_item">
    Item 2
    <a href="https://www.site2.com">link2</a>
    </div>
    ,
    ,
    ,
  ```
- You want to retrieve the values of `item 1 item 3 item 5` from `<div class="list_item">` using `Parser` of the Google Apps Script library.

#### Modification points:

- In your case, how about using `iterate()` instead of `build()` for `Parser`?
- And also, it is required to process the retrieved values. In this case, I used XmlService.

#### Modified script:

```
function getData() {
  var url = "https://here_goes_webpage_url.com";
  var fromText = '<div class="list_item">';
  var toText = '</div>';
  
  var content = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();

  // I modified below script.
  var positions = [1, 3, 5];  // Please set the position of `list_item` you want.
  var scraped = Parser
    .data(content)
    .from(fromText)
    .to(toText)
    .iterate()
    .map(e => XmlService.parse(fromText + e + toText).getRootElement().getContent(0).getValue().trim());
  var res = positions.map(e => scraped[e - 1]);
  console.log(res);  // When your HTML data is used, [ 'Item 1', 'Item 3', 'Item 5' ] is retrieved.
  return res;
}
```

#### Note:

- This modified script supposes the unit structure is `<div class="list_item">Item 1<a href="https://www.site1.com">link1</a></div>`. So if your actual situation is different from this structure, this modified script might not be used. Please be careful this.
- Please use this script with enabling V8.

#### References:

- [Parser](https://www.kutil.org/2016/01/easy-data-scrapping-with-google-apps.html)
- [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service)

Comment: Hi @Tanaike thank you for posting this approach. I tried using it but I am getting an error `Content is not allowed in prolog.` on this line `.map(e => XmlService.parse(fromText + e + toText).getRootElement().getContent(0).getValue().trim());`

Comment: @kuml Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. In that case, it is considered that your sample HTML in your question might be different from your actual HTML. So in this case, it is required to replicate your situation. Because when I used your sample HTML, no error occurs. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. So can you provide the sample HTML for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it. How about this?

Comment: Hi @Tanaike thanks for your quick response. Actually your solution gave me an idea to try something and it seems to be working. I simply did this: `var scraped = Parser.data(content).from(fromText).to(toText).iterate();` and then calling `scraped[0]` or  `scraped[1]` and so on individually

Comment: @kuml Thank you for replying. Yes. At `Parser`, when `iterate()` is used instead of `build()`, when the retrieved values have the multiple values, those are put in an array. But in your question, I thought that you want to retrieve the values of `item 1 item 3 item 5` from the HTML retrieved by `Parser`. So as additional process, I proposed to use XmlService for retrieving it. But your sample HTML seems different from your actual one. I think that by this, such error occurs. If you are not required to use the additional process, please remove it. I deeply apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: ah that was probably my fault that I did not explain it correctly. I am simply trying to get content of an element and when I say content, i meant iteration since in my case there are multiple iteration of html elements with same class. Thanks for your help and asking right questions and providing the code that gave me an approach to solve this problem.

Comment: @kuml Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Can I ask you about whether your issue was resolved? Unfortunately, from your replying and your situation, I couldn't understand about it. I apologize for this again.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike yes problem was resolved. Thanks for you help!